# SAP UI5 Search - Binding to XML-View

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sapui5

I am trying to build an SAPUI5 application to show the current transports in my company. As datasource we`re using an SAP Backend-Service which is referenced in the manifest.json.

My metadata.xml:

```
<EntityType Name="Transporteintrag" sap:content-version="1">
   <Key>
       <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
   </Key>
   <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" sap:label="Zahl" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
   <Property Name="Land" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3" sap:label="Land" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
   <Property Name="Kunnr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Warenempfänger" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
   <Property Name="Name1" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30" sap:label="Name 1" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
   <Property Name="AnzMat" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" sap:label="Zahl" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
   <Property Name="Gesber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Characterfeld der Länge 10" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
   <Property Name="Tknum" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Transportnummer" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="ZVERSAND_SRV_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
    <EntitySet Name="Transporteintrag_S" EntityType="ZVERSAND_SRV.Transporteintrag" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
    <EntitySet Name="Transporteintrag_T" EntityType="ZVERSAND_SRV.Transporteintrag" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
    <EntitySet Name="Transporteintrag_F" EntityType="ZVERSAND_SRV.Transporteintrag" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
    <EntitySet Name="Transporteintrag_D" EntityType="ZVERSAND_SRV.Transporteintrag" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
</EntityContainer>
```

I built the view by using XML and data-bindings to connect with my model.

Page1.view.xml

```
<SearchField xmlns="sap.m" width="100%" placeholder="Suchen" id="__field0" liveChange="handleLiveSearch"/>

<Table id="Table_0_0" width="100%" noDataText="Das ist jetzt doof ..." mode="None" showSeparators="All" growing="true" growingThreshold="5000" growingScrollToLoad="true" items="{/Transporteintrag_D}">
<columns>
    <Column hAlign="Left" vAlign="Top" minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" mergeDuplicates="false">
        <header>
            <Text text="WE" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="true" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit" class="custom_font_table"/>
        </header>
        <footer/>
    </Column>
</columns>
<items>
    <ColumnListItem type="Active">
        <cells>
            <Text text="{= ${Name1}.substr(0,30)}" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit" class="custom_font_table row_height"/>
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
</items>
<headerToolbar>
    <core:Fragment xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" fragmentName="Versand_Clean.view.TableHeaderFragment" type="XML" id="__toolbar_X0"/>
</headerToolbar>
</Table>
```

The `DataBinding` is working fine. However, when opening the application in the browser all data is displayed in my `sap.m.table`.

To give the enduser more usability I´m trying to implement a live-search-field.

Here is my Problem:
I´m build the liveChange function in my Page1.controller.js

```
handleLiveSearch: function (oEvent) {
   var searchQuery = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
   var oFilter = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("WE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchQuery)];
   var oView = this.getView();
   var oTable = oView.byId("Table_0_0");
   var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
   if(searchQuery === "")
   {
       oBinding.filter( [] );
       oBinding.refresh(true);
   }
   else
   {
       oBinding.filter(oFilter);
       oBinding.refresh(true);
   }
}
```

My problem occurs by typing in the searchField. After typing of the first char my table isn't displays any data. When I empty the searchfield my data is displayed again.

What is wrong with my code ?

**Edit:**
To check if the filter applied to the table i opend the Google Chrome Developer Tools and the Tag Sources. Now i was able to see that the filter applied to the table. But the the Table still not update the values.
[image]

In the Table currently are 3 Values. Only one contains "Delphi".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with filter that property which you are trying doesn't exist in the metadata.

```
 var oFilter = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("WE", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchQuery)];
```

Change **WE** with **Name1**.

```
var oFilter = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchQuery)];
```

Comment: I`ve tried this solution. But the search function still not working. After typing of my table is the same as before. Nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Saddamhussain's edit it has to be:

```
oBinding.filter(oFilter, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

Comment: Nothing change to his answer. I edited my post. The filter is aplied to the oTable as you can see. But the Table in the Browser still not updating.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the contains operator. This operator is not working correctly in SAP's OData implementation. You can use a little trick and apply a `tolower` function when you create a filter like this:

```
var searchQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase();
// this step is important for the OData query
searchQuery = "'" + searchQuery + "'"; 
var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("tolower(Name1)", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchQuery);
var oFilter = [ filter ];
```

On the other hand you can use another compare operator like `EQ` but then your search string must match exactly:

```
var oFilter = [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, searchQuery)];
```